# WordPress function.php and post.php permission are changing automatically

Tags: wordpress

WordPress theme/function.php and wp-includes/post.php permission are changing automatically and permission 000 please help me

Comment: check once by deactivate your all plugin & use updated wordpress version.

Comment: maulikbhai everything is latest, brother, come to me every day 1 problem is coming

Comment: wordpress latest and all plugin latest version Brothers are also coming to the Problem

Comment: Then it's sure about modification comes from your server side. contact to your server support team.

Comment: okay bhai np thank you help

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue. In my site, all theme's functions.php file has malicious code which was changing file permission to 200.

Answer (score 0):

this problem is related to hosting and I also face this problem but didn't get any code related solution. But yes most of places I got this as a hosting related problem and for this need to contact your hosting provider and tell them about this problem and they will fix it.
If any one get any code which stop auto modify permission problem. Most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the code to stop it. but I am using this so all modified files will revert to 604 permission, as I am checking on it to where the change came from. place this at the top of index.php in the main/root of wordpress.

```
<?php
chmod("/{Directory Link to your file}/mythemes/functions.php", 0604);
```

This worked for me to make the site stay alive. for now....